# R - Correlation test over all data frames in list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list (top30clean) containing 21 data frames labelled `b1` to `b21`, each with three variables - `Station`, `Rainfall`, `Origin`.

I was hoping to perform the correlation test  for each dataframe for the same two variables `Rainfall` & `Origin`

```
cor <- lapply(top30clean, cor(top30clean$Rainfall, top30clean$Origin, method = c('pearson')
```

I know the above code is wrong af, but I'm not sure where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anonymous function in `lapply` :

```
cor <- lapply(top30clean, function(x) cor(x$Rainfall, x$Origin, method = 'pearson'))
```

Since `cor` function would return a single number as output you can also use `sapply` to get vector output in `cor`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(top30clean, ~  cor(.x$Rainfall, .x$Origin, method = 'pearson'))
```